# Underlying class changes between serialisation and deserialisation

Tags: python-2.7, serialization, pickle

There is an object of `testclass` created at some point in the life of program and then it is serialized in file system using `pickle` or `h5py`. Now during this period the definition of `testclass` is updated. The update is always about adding new fields (and not removing existing ones).

Does deserializing the stored class back and referencing it using updated `testclass` definition a right approach?

**Before Serialization:** Class is defined

```
class testclass:
    __fieldA = None
    __fieldB = None
    __fieldC = 'Hello'
    def __init__(self, A, B):
        self.__fieldA = A
        self.__fieldB = B
    def setA(self, A):
        self.__fieldA = A
    def getA(self):
        return self.__fieldA
    def setB(self, B):
        self.__fieldB = B
    def getB(self):
        return self.__fieldB
    def setC(self, C):
        self.__fieldC = C
    def getC(self):
        return self.__fieldC

>>>orig_obj = testclass('testA', 'testB')
>>>isinstance(orig_obj, testclass)
>>>True
>>>with open('test', 'wb') as handle:
      pickle.dump(orig_obj, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

**After Serialization:** Class definition is changed

```
class testclass:
    __fieldA = None
    __fieldB = None
    __fieldC = 'Hello'
    __fieldD = 10
    def __init__(self, A, B):
        self.__fieldA = A
        self.__fieldB = B
    def setA(self, A):
        self.__fieldA = A
    def getA(self):
        return self.__fieldA
    def setB(self, B):
        self.__fieldB = B
    def getB(self):
        return self.__fieldB
    def setC(self, C):
        self.__fieldC = C
    def getC(self):
        return self.__fieldC
    def setD(self, D):
        self.__fieldD = D
    def getD(self):
        return self.__fieldD

>>>with open('test', 'rb') as handle:
       loaded_obj = pickle.load(handle)
>>>isinstance(loaded_obj, testclass)
>>>False
```

Now `loaded_obj` is not an instance of `testclass`. This makes sense and has nothing to do with the fact whether new field `__fieldD` is introduced or not.

In this scenario, what is the best way to ensure that `loaded_obj` is an instance of `testclass`?

Comment: I don't think the `h5py` tag is relevant.  That file format saves `numpy` arrays, not custom classes.  You could define class methods that save and load variables with `h5py`, but that code has to handle the absence of new variables (datasets) itself.

Comment: sure. Deleting it now